# How to center images inside div that are float left

Tags: html, css

my website is [watersedgeofshelton.com](http://watersedgeofshelton.com/floor-plans) and on the "floor plans" page I have two images side by side that use the code float:left
my problem is that I can not get them centered on the page and also still be side by side

thank you!

```
div#floorplans {
text-align: center;
}
div#admiral {
float: left;
padding-right: 20px;
}
div#clipper {
float: left;
}
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: why can't you simply remove those floats?

Comment: @ISuthanBala because then the images aren't next to eachother they are beneath each other

Comment: Use `display: inline-block` or `flex` instead of `float: left`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code to your CSS and check your page -

```
div#admiral,
div#clipper {
    width: 50%;
}
```

and remove this one -

```
div#admiral {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove float from each div#admiral and div#clipper and then goto div#floorplans and add the following

```
div#floorplans {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove Float 
2) use table or ul li (with horizontal nav and hiding bullets) for images  to show side by side.
3) use "align-text:center"; if you want div the use "margin:0 auto"

Hope it help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not *try* something like this?

Put the floating **divs/images** inside a **wrapper** set a width for the **wrapper** and set a **margin auto** for the **wrapper**!